# Where to type my code in relation to main boilerplate code inserted by IDE

Tags: python, program-entry-point, function

My IDE always automatically inserts the below code into my Python projects whenever I create a new file.

```
def main():
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I know what this code does vis-a-vis the ordering of functions, but I'm not sure where I type my code in relation to this code.

I've seen many examples where programmers type their code after this entire block of code (after the second "main()" occurrence). But, I've also seen some examples of programmers typing their code between "pass" and "if".

What's the accepted convention? Why?

Answer (score 1):

The contents of the `if __name__ == '__main__':` block are executed only if you run the script (not import it), so it doesn't really matter if you do:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

Or:

```
def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The first one is shorter, but the second one exposes a `main()` method which you can call from another module. Unless you expect that the `main()` method will be called from another module, it's personal preference.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense. I'll choose the second way of doing this so that I can call the 'main()' method from another module, if need be. One last question, would it be customary to indent everything 4 spaces within that method?

Comment: @SteffiBane: Four spaces *everywhere* is common. Just be consistent (don't mix two spaces and four spaces, tabs and spaces, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It is simply giving you a starting point. The `def main():` part sets up a method. You can put your code in there. Note that you don't have to. The

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

part checks whether the program is being run without importing. If so, then it runs main();

Answer (score 0):

You can type you code in either of the places you mentioned..

Coding within the main() function seems better as it is well organized.

Answer (score 0):

If you want, just delete the default code and start typing.